# NullPointerException when showing JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I show a JFileChooser with this snippet:

```
public File getDestination() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        return chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return new File(".");
}
```

Usually, the first time it's showed, it displays & works correctly. The second time, it will always throw this exception:

```
Exception in thread "Basic L&F File Loading Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.pidlsEqual(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.equals(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.isFileSystemRoot(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.isFileSystemRoot(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.isFileSystemRoot(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.filechooser.WindowsFileSystemView.isTraversable(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.isTraversable(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$LoadFilesThread.run0(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$LoadFilesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Java -version says:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And the thread I found [here](http://www.dbvis.com/forum/message.jspa?messageID=10866) says I should downgrade the Java version. Should I follow their advice, or is there something I could have done wrong?

Comment: regardless of your question:
why do you return "new File(".")" when "showSaveDialog" returns anything that is not JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION? (e.g. CANCEL_OPTION or ERROR_OPTION)

Comment: because I'm saving in the app's working directory.

Comment: Note 6u19 and 6u20 are security releases, so be very careful downgrading.

Comment: Looks like it is in a restartable thread? Does the application keep running? If so does it matter? I guess you might need to revalidate the file cache.

Comment: Oh, and if there isn't already one, a bug report might be a good idea.

Comment: The application keeps running, because I'm catching the exception. It may be possible to have it working this way, but I hate seeing exception traces in my logs. Bug reports seem to exist on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really looks like it's a version problem / regression.
So the answer would hence be: follow their advice, you haven't done anything wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in build 1.6u21

See here:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6940843